# How to change overlay map from toggle to hold?

Tags: diablo-iii

When you press "Tab" the overlay map will show up on your screen.

Is there a way to have this be a "hold" feature instead of a "toggle" feature?

Comment: Edited the question title for clarity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same question when the game was released and I've checked everything in game and I've searched online and it's not possible.
Eventually you'll just get used to pressing TAB twice.

Comment: Thanks for the replies.  I'll select an answer after a day or so.

Answer (score 1):

There currently is no option in-game to toggle the map to hold. You can look in the key-bindings, but I don't think there is an option in there either. If it exists, it will be located in key-bindings. But again, I don't think it's in there. It may have been added, but I haven't seen it.

Answer (score -2):

Buy an expensive keyboard that allows remapping (anything from Razer, Steelseries, etc).

You can probably get software that does the same thing.

Map Tab-down to Tab
Map Tab-up to Tab
You might have to turn key repeat off - or holding tab might spam tab.

This will be annoying outside of Diablo so you wan't to be able to turn this setting on/off easily. Fancy gaming keyboards all allow you to switch mapping profiles with a key-press.

Don't go nuts with your re-mapping. It's against the rules to perform more than one action per key-press (so you can't make a key that spams 1234 for example).

Bonus: While you're at it, re-map Tab to Shift on your keyboard, then change the map key in Diablo to Shift as well. Now you'll never accidentally alt tab while looting and mapping.